# Можно ли прочитать аргументы, с которыми программа вызывает функцию в dll-файле?

Tags: windows, dll

Есть программа, которая вызывает функции из dll-файла.
Можно ли каким-то отладчиком или чем-то подобным узнать, что за функции и с какими аргументами она вызывает?

Comment: 1. Подмените dll на свою с такими же экспортируемыми функциями, или
2. Присоедините отладчик и поставьте на вызов функции точку останова

Answer (score 1):

Список экспортируемых (и импортируемых) функций узнать не проблема. Например в [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Но вот параметры вызова можно узнать, если изучить код, или поискать описание в [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)